# Android studio fragment not responding to back pressed button

Tags: android, button, fragment, back

i have only one activity and alot of fragment in my app

everything worked fine unitl i added this code to my **loginFragment**

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    SPManager.init(getContext().getApplicationContext());
    if(SPManager.isLogged()){
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.host_fragment);
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_login_to_mainFragment);

    }
}
```

now the **back Button** works everywhere except in the mainFragment , i want it to exit from the app when it pressed .

i looked at others code but none of the answers worked for me .
i'm using the Navigation architecture and all of my fragments are linked correctly by actions

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your main activity which you want to finish after backbutton pressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Exit");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure, you want to exit?");
    builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
```